# How to insert a function into a class in VB.NET using Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, code-analysis, visual-studio-extensions

I have some logic to add a function to class using Roslyn, which works with a C# project, but not with a VB project. I am using the **DocumentEditor** editor class (*Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.DocumentEditor*) to perform the update.

I start by finding the **SyntaxNode** corresponding to the class definition.

In C# this is a **ClassDeclarationSyntax** element.

[image: Screenshot of Syntax Visualizer for VB class]

In VB this is a **ClassBlockSyntax** element.

[image: Screenshot of Syntax Visualizer for VB class]

I generate the complete text of the new function in a string variable, and then create a SyntaxNode from the text.

For C# I use the method **CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText**, approximately as follows:

```
var Tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText ( Code, CSharpParseOptions.Default ) ;
var Root = await Tree.GetRootAsync() as CompilationUnitSyntax ;
var Expr = Root.Members.FirstOrDefault()
                       .WithAdditionalAnnotations ( Formatter.Annotation ) ;
```

Expr is then of type **MethodDeclarationSyntax**.

For VB I use the method **VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText**, with almost identical code:

```
var Tree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText ( Code ) ;
var Root = await Tree.GetRootAsync() as CompilationUnitSyntax ;
var Expr = Root.Members.FirstOrDefault() ;
```

In this case Expr is of type **MethodBlockSyntax**.

I then try to insert the new node into the class.

For C# I use

```
RoslynDocEditor.InsertAfter ( RoslynClass.ChildNodes.Last, Expr )
```

where RoslynClass is the ClassBlockSyntax node, and a little later ...

```
RootNode  = RoslynDocEditor.GetChangedRoot()
RootNode  = Formatter.Format ( RootNode, Formatter.Annotation, VSWorkspace )
RoslynDoc = RoslynDoc.WithSyntaxRoot ( RootNode )
ApplyOK   = VSWorkspace.TryApplyChanges ( RoslynDoc.Project.Solution )
```

This adds the new function at the end of the class.

If I do the same for VB, it generates an **InvalidOperationException** at the line

```
RootNode  = RoslynDocEditor.GetChangedRoot()
```

with the description *"The item specified is not the element of a list"* and the stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.NodeListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitClassBlock(ClassBlockSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.ClassBlockSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.BaseListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.NodeListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitListElement[TNode](TNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitList[TNode](SyntaxList`1 list)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.NodeListEditor.VisitList[TNode](SyntaxList`1 list)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.VisitCompilationUnit(CompilationUnitSyntax node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.CompilationUnitSyntax.Accept[TResult](VisualBasicSyntaxVisitor`1 visitor)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxRewriter.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.BaseListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.NodeListEditor.Visit(SyntaxNode node)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxReplacer.InsertNodeInList(SyntaxNode root, SyntaxNode nodeInList, IEnumerable`1 nodesToInsert, Boolean insertBefore)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.VisualBasicSyntaxNode.InsertNodesInListCore(SyntaxNode nodeInList, IEnumerable`1 nodesToInsert, Boolean insertBefore)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNodeExtensions.InsertNodesBefore[TRoot](TRoot root, SyntaxNode nodeInList, IEnumerable`1 newNodes)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicSyntaxGenerator.InsertDeclarationsBeforeInternal(SyntaxNode root, SyntaxNode declaration, IEnumerable`1 newDeclarations)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicSyntaxGenerator._Closure$__310-0._Lambda$__0(SyntaxNode r)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxGenerator.PreserveTrivia[TNode](TNode node, Func`2 nodeChanger)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.CodeGeneration.VisualBasicSyntaxGenerator.InsertNodesBefore(SyntaxNode root, SyntaxNode declaration, IEnumerable`1 newDeclarations)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxEditor.InsertChange.Apply(SyntaxNode root, SyntaxGenerator generator)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxEditor.GetChangedRoot()
at MultiLang.frmLanguageSwitching.VB$StateMachine_133_btAdd_Click.MoveNext() in C:\VSPackage_Version_7_1\Project\MultiLang\Forms\frmLanguageSwitching.vb:line 944
```

From the screen shot of the Syntax Visualizer you can see that the last child of the ClassBlock is the **EndClassStatement**, so it makes more sense to use

```
RoslynDocEditor.InsertBefore ( RoslynClass.ChildNodes.Last, NewFunctionNode )
```

but that generates exactly the same error as above.

Is there a way to insert a function in VB class in a similar manner, or does this only work in C#.

Comment: I would file this under http://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/new it looks like a bug

Comment: Thanks. I will wait a day or two, but I don't get an answer will create an issue on Github.

Comment: I will do. I think there is a two day delay before you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for VB, if I cast the ClassNode from a **SyntaxNode** (back) to **ClassBlockSyntax** and then use the **Members** collection

```
var cbs = ClassNode as Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Syntax.ClassBlockSyntax ;
RoslynDocEditor.InsertAfter ( cbs.Members.Last(), Expr ) ;
```

The same works for C#, if I cast the ClassNode to **ClassDeclarationSyntax**

```
var cds = ClassNode as Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ClassDeclarationSyntax ;
RoslynDocEditor.InsertAfter ( cds.Members.Last(), Expr ) ;
```

but as already described, for C# it also works with

```
RoslynDocEditor.InsertAfter ( RoslynClass.ChildNodes.Last, Expr ) ;
```

So it looks like **SyntaxNode.ChildNodes** is equivalent to **ClassDeclarationSyntax.Members** for C#, but not equivalent to **ClassBlockSyntax.Members** for VB.

---

**EDIT**

It looks like an easier and a better solution is to use the **AddMember** extension method:

```
RoslynDocEditor.AddMember ( RoslynClass, expr )
```